# UIScrollView, how to set size to image size?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming

I have UIScrollView, with an UIImageView on top.  I have a couple things I am trying to fix:

1)  Initially, the image is scaled to fit in the screen (this is good).  How do I set a boundary so that you can not zoom out past this point (I don't want to see any of the background)?

I looked around for some sort of `maxSize` property but couldn't find anything.

2)  How do I set the amount that someone can zoom in?  I don't want users to be able to x8 or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 )

```
[scrollview setMinimumZoomScale : float];
```

2 )

```
[scrollview setMaximumZoomScale : float];
```